# 70s Book about an intergalactic cruise

Tags: story-identification, books, illustrated-story

When I was a kid I had this large (coffee table-ish) hard cover illustrated book, which was basically a travel-companion guide for people going on this intergalactic cruise.  The whole thing was spun (basically) as a brochure for all these different exotic destinations that the cruise would visit.  It was (as I recall) incredibly well crafted, with a lot of very clever detail and gorgeous art.

Comment: Not the answer (and indeed has little in common with the work you seek) but your question reminds me of the veritable Robert Silverberg short story "Schwartz Between the Galaxies", which is [available in audio form](http://escapepod.org/2008/04/10/ep153-schwartz-between-the-galaxies/) on [EscapePod](http://escapepod.org).

Comment: better duplicate target at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244217/early-1980s-graphic-novel-about-human-spies-undercover-on-an-intergalactic-cruis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“Tour of the Universe”...? You can buy second-hand copies on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/0905310365/ref=dp_olp_0?ie=UTF8&condition=all).

Comment: YES! that is totally it! thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: Can you provide some information why you felt this was a good match?

Comment: @valorum what was a good match? I'm not sure what you mean with your question - assuming you are asking me.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel  - Actually it was aimed at JoshB. I was hoping he could flesh out his answer a little and explain why this book matches the question.

Comment: Because the book I had was a big coffee table sized book that looked like the travel documents and brochures you end up at the end of a cruise... Ie, it matches the question.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't Sci-Fi, but your description makes me think of the book ["Galaxies."](http://www.timothyferris.com/books/Galaxies.html)  It's non-fiction with lots of information on stars, galaxies, etc., but I'm pretty sure there's an overall narrative that runs through the book presenting the information as if to passengers on an intergalactic cruise.  It certainly has beautiful pictures.